# Adding search functionality in a bootstrap accordion control

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am trying to implement a search ability to a Bootstrap collapse/accordion component.  The feature works....kind of.  The problem I am having is tying together the actual bootstrap functionality to the search term and how the control opens and closes.

The search term should look at the lowest level of the array and open the panels if the search term is included in that text value.

I am using Knockout JS to control the viewmodel and obviously Bootstrap for the component display.

http://jsfiddle.net/ascendantofrain/d0rt2b29/6/

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/html" id="accordion-template">
    <!-- ko foreach: accordionData -->
        <div class="grouping-wrapper">
            <div class="group-by">
                <!-- ko if: $parent.searchEnabled -->
                <input type="search" class="search-input show" name="search_group-by" placeholder="Search" data-bind="textInput: $parent.searchTerm" />
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="group-dropdown" data-bind="css: $parent.helperClass">
                    <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'accordion-' + id }" class="group-dropdown-top-level">
                        <!-- ko if: $data.hasOwnProperty('children') && children.length > 0 -->
                        <div class="panel" data-bind="foreach: children">
                            <!-- ko if: $parents[1].leafNodesCount($data) > 0 -->
                            <span data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="attr: { 'data-parent': '#accordion-' + $parent.id, href: '#collapse-' + id }, css: 'group-' + ($index() + 1)">
                                <!-- ko text: text --><!-- /ko -->
                                <i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i>
                            </span>
                            <div class="collapse group-dropdown-second-level" data-bind="attr: { id: 'collapse-' + id, 'isOpen': li_attr.isOpen }">
                                <!-- ko if: $data.hasOwnProperty('children') && children.length > 0 -->
                                <div class="panel" data-bind="foreach: children">
                                    <!-- ko if: children.length > 0 -->
                                    <span data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="attr: { 'data-parent': '#collapse-' + $parent.id, href: '#collapse-' + id }">
                                        <!-- ko text: text --><!-- /ko -->
                                        <i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="collapse group-dropdown-third-level" data-bind="attr: { id: 'collapse-' + id, 'isHierarchy': li_attr.isHierarchy, 'isOpen': li_attr.isOpen }">
                                        <!-- ko if: $data.hasOwnProperty('children') && children.length > 0 -->
                                        <!-- ko foreach: children -->
                                        <div class="panel" data-bind="click: $parents[3].action, text: text, css: { in: $parents[3].search($data) }"></div>
                                        <!-- /ko -->
                                        <!-- /ko -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /ko -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>

<accordion params="data: metricData, searchEnabled: true"></accordion>
```

**JS**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.accordionToggleNodePropertyOnClick = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        //$(element).on('click', function() {
        //    options.property(!options.property());
        //});
    }
};

ko.components.register('accordion', {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        var self = this;

        self.accordionData = params.data || [];
        self.accordionType = params.accordionType || 'default';
        self.searchEnabled = params.searchEnabled || false;
        self.panelPrefix = params.panelPrefix || 'collapse';
        self.helperClass = params.helperClass || '';

        self.leafNodesCount = function (node) {
            var cnt = 0;
            _.each(node.children, function (c) {
                _.each(c.children, function () {
                    cnt++;
                });
            });
            return cnt;
        };

        self.action = function () {
            var action = params.action || 'default';

            if (action === 'none') {
                return;
            }
            if (action === 'pivot') {}
        };

        self.searchTerm = ko.observable('');
        self.search = function (node) {
            if (self.searchTerm() && self.searchTerm().length >= 3) {
                _.each(self.accordionData, function (c) {
                    _.each(c.children, function (c1) {
                        var open1 = _.find(c1.children, function (c2) {
                            return c2.li_attr.isOpen() === true;
                        });
                        c1.li_attr.isOpen(open1 ? true : false);                        

                        if (open1) {
                            $('#' + self.panelPrefix + '-' + c1.id).collapse('show');
                        } else {
                            $('#' + self.panelPrefix + '-' + c1.id).collapse('hide');
                        }

                        _.each(c1.children, function (c2) {
                            var open = _.find(c2.children, function (c3) {
                                return c3.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchTerm()) !== -1;
                            });
                            c2.li_attr.isOpen(open ? true : false);

                            if (open) {
                                $('#' + self.panelPrefix + '-' + c2.id).collapse('show');
                            } else {
                                $('#' + self.panelPrefix + '-' + c2.id).collapse('hide');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });

                return node.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchTerm()) !== -1 ? true : false;
            }
        };

        self.toggleOpen = function(node) {

        };
    },
    template: {
        element: 'accordion-template'
    }
});

function daVM() {
    // Define Alerts Configuration
    self.metricData = [{
        id: '1',
        text: 'Define Alerts Metric Tab',
        children: [{
            id: '1-1',
            text: 'First',
            li_attr: {
                isOpen: ko.observable(false)
            },
            children: [{
                id: '2-1',
                text: 'Second Level 1',
                li_attr: {
                    isHierarchy: false,
                    isOpen: ko.observable(false)
                },
                children: [{
                    id: '2-3-4',
                    text: 'Thard Level 1',
                    li_attr: {
                        isHierarchy: false,
                        isOpen: ko.observable(false)
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                id: '3-1',
                text: 'Second Level 2',
                li_attr: {
                    isHierarchy: false,
                    isOpen: ko.observable(false)
                },
                children: [{
                    id: '3-1',
                    text: 'Third Level 1',
                    li_attr: {
                        isHierarchy: false,
                        isOpen: ko.observable(false)
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                id: '4-1',
                text: 'Second Level 3',
                li_attr: {
                    isHierarchy: false,
                    isOpen: ko.observable(false)
                },
                children: [{
                    id: '4-1',
                    text: 'Therd Level 1',
                    li_attr: {
                        isHierarchy: false,
                        isOpen: ko.observable(false)
                    }
                }]
            }],
        }]
    }];
}

ko.applyBindings(new daVM());
```

Comment: I can't see where you're calling the `search` function from. Shouldn't there be some handler which captures changes to `searchTerm` and calls `search`? Or possibly: why not add a *subscribe* handler to `searchTerm` and move the *search* logic in there? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables

Comment: The search function gets called automatically from the textInput binding on the search bar.  Also, I'm not 100% certain the search function is the issue, I'm having more of an issue with keeping the bootstrap accordion in sync with the search.